# How to modify Author field of ListItem

Tags: list-item, updatelistitems, properties, csom

I am building a migration tool that is migrating items from an `XML` schema to SharePoint list fields. Everything is working fine except when it comes to the migration of `Created By` fields. I need to use the client object model to do this.

So far this is what I have:

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{
      List lst = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("list name");
      Field field = lst.Fields.GetByTitle("Created By");
      field.ReadOnlyField = false; //Allow the field to be modified

      //...Get all list items and store in ListItemCollection named 'col'
      foreach (ListItem item in col)
      {
           item["Author"] = xmlNodeValue; //Take the User form the xml schema and insert into sharepoint's created by field
           item.Update();
           ctx.Credentials = creds;
           ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      }
}
```

The exception thrown when executing against the server:

`Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.`

I realize that I probably can't store a string of `xmlNodeValue` in that field, so how can I achieve this?

Also please keep in mind that the user name pulled from `xmlNodeValue` may not exist as a claims user.

Comment: 1. Author field can not be set programmatically using CSOM. Eq. field 'Editor' you can set or another user field you can set too.

2. Code i next post `sourceCtx.Web.EnsureUser(val.LookupValue)` is bad, because use user display text for find object user. Use `sourceCtx.Web.GetUserById(val.LookupId)`

Comment: In case if you someone want to achieve same functionality using REST API on Sharepoint Online the code snippet is available here https://anomepani.github.io/

Answer (score 3):

In order to modify/update the Author field using the client object model, you need to make sure to

- Load the Source Item
- Load the User Object with Source Context
- Ensure the User Object in the Destination Context
- Insert the User Object in the Destination Item
- Update the Destination Item

Please find below the pseudo code.

```
sourceCtx.Load(sourceItem);
sourceCtx.ExecuteQuery();

FieldUserValue val = sourceItem["Author"] as FieldUserValue;

User user = sourceCtx.Web.EnsureUser(val.LookupValue);
sourceCtx.Load(user);
sourceCtx.ExecuteQuery();

newDestItem["Author"] = destinationCtx.Web.EnsureUser(user.LoginName);
newDestItem.Update();
```

Please let me know if you have any further queries.

Thanks, Dinesh

Answer (score 1):

Update Author and Editor at the same time for the first version only or Final file without versions.

```
if (firstVersion || noVersion)
{
authorUserName = ((FieldUserValue)liSource["Author"]).Email;
User author = contextDest.Web.EnsureUser(authorUserName);

if (author != null)
{
    contextDest.Load(liDest, l => l["Author"], l => l["Editor"], l => l["Created"]);
    contextDest.ExecuteQuery();

    // IMPORTANT: Must be same name to get author updated
    liDest["Editor"] = author;
    liDest["Author"] = author;
    liDest["Created"] = liSource["Created"];
    liDest["Modified"] = liSource["Modified"];
    liDest.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
    contextDest.ExecuteQuery();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Web.EnsureUser` method to get the `User` object and then use that to update the `Author`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.ensureuser.aspx